# How to declare child pointer with parent from different structs in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, a-star

I want to connect child on line `no->rodzic = tz;` to pointer `tz` which points to "parent", but those are 2 different structs. Is it possible to do like I think? My ERROR is: `cannot convert...` etc in assignment

```
struct lotwarta {
    int wartosc,x,y;
    lotwarta *parent;
};
struct lzamknieta {
    int wartosc,x,y;
    lzamknieta *parent;
    lzamknieta *tz; 
};

lzamknieta *nz;
nz = new lzamknieta; // do listy zamknietej dodajemy 1 element
nz->wartosc = 0;
nz->x = startx;
nz->y = starty;
nz->parent = NULL;
lzamknieta* tz = nz;

lotwarta *no;
no = new lotwarta;
no->wartosc = 0;
no->x = startx;
no->y = starty;
no->parent = NULL;

cout << no->rodzic << endl;
lotwarta *to = no;

if( (y!=1) && (G[y-1][x]!=5) )
{
    no = new lotwarta;
    no->wartosc = euklides(x,y-1);
    no->x = x;
    no->y = y-1;
    no->parent = tz; <- here I have this error
}
```

Comment: Not expansive enough. Please include the class definitions.

Comment: If the `rodzik` element of `lotwarta` is not a `lzamknieta *`, the assignment is doomed to failure unless, perhaps, there is an inheritance relationship between the two classes.

Comment: If not translate the names to english You could at least format the code.

Comment: no, you cant assign a pointer to one struct to a pointer to another. but since they are so similar, maby you only need one kind?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what this code should do,
but you can assign a pointer of a type to another type by simply casting its value:

```
no->rodzic = reinterpret_cast<lzamknieta*>(tz); //in this case tz would be casted to a pointer of type lzamknieta
```

But it is not always a good idea, to cast a pointer to another type, it depends on the context.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  If the advice you give is followed, you can watch the code crash and burn later!  It is premature to answer the question; there isn't enough information to give a reliable answer, and the answer most probably does not involve a `reinterpret_cast`.  If the type of `rodzic` is correct, a `lzamknieta *`, there is no need for the cast.  If the type of `rodzic` is incorrect, no amount of casting will fix the code reliably.